# How do I ensure that all controllers in an asp.net web-api service are configured correctly _in a single test class_?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, reflection, asp.net-web-api

Dipping my toes into asp.net and mvc, more specifically the web-api (2.0) part of MVC 5, I like the idea of using attributes and creating your own attribute classes to control how requests are handled and responses returned for all api end-points.

The ["How to test "Only certain roles should have access to a controller in MVC"](http://www.bryanavery.co.uk/post/2013/04/30/How-to-test-Only-certain-roles-should-have-access-to-a-controller-in-MVC.aspx) article describes how to unit test a single controller to ensure that it keeps the correct attributes and doesn't get undesired attributes added.

That is a perfectly valid way of unit testing individual controllers. However, I prefer to have all tests of the API configuration in a single place instead of spread around unit tests of individual controllers. Especially as, using [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), a controller can very easily be replaced by a different controller which may not have the correct attributes and whose test companion doesn't test for them.

What I envision is a single test class where all aspects of the API configuration can be secured against undesired effects of (inadvertent) changes. What I am struggling with is how to set this up. Bryan Avery's article (mentioned above) shows how to get a list of the custom attributes of a controller class, but:

**how do I get my hands on a list of all controllers present in the test project?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflection ought to help you here:

```
var myControllers = Assembly.Load(yourAssemblyName)
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => typeof(t).IsAssignableFrom(ApiController))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I copy-pasted from a similar project, as I had a need for this myself once. ;)

Comment: Just a typo: `.Where(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ApiController)))`

Answer (score 1):

This worked in ASP.Net Core, based on [Haney's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18409948/270155) but with the Where clause reversed.

```
var controllers = typeof(Startup)
.Assembly
.GetTypes()
.Where(t => typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller).IsAssignableFrom(t))
.ToList();
```